# NoClassDefFoundError with multiple dex (Device API < 21)

Tags: android, noclassdeffounderror, android-multidex

I can build project successfully and run normally on my phone `API = 23`. However, when I tested with another device `API = 19`, the app crashed with `E/UncaughtException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`. This is the full log:

[image]
[image]

Does anyone has any suggestion?
P/s: I enabled `Multidex` already.

**Edit**: I tried to build release-apk and it did work normally on all devices. Hence the problem only occurs in the debug apk.

Comment: you've looked at the docs for pre-5.0 multidex? https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html#mdex-pre-l ... that is probably your issue..

Comment: Don't post your logs as an image but as text, please ...